# Power BI not displaying full data

Tags: sql, oracle, powerbi

I use DB visualizer to execute queries and get results from an oracle database, and I use Microsoft Power BI to display the results. On August 20, 2018 I updated Power BI and installed the latest version and since that time, the results in the Power BI query editor is not the same as the results in the Database.
I have a table with 8 columns, 7 of type string and one of type Timestamp and here's an example picture of the resulted query
[image]

And when running the same query in Power BI the result is not the same
[image]

Do you guys know anything or a way of fixing this issue? if you need more info please let me know

Comment: Have you checked your connection?

Comment: @KamilG.,Connection is working fine, how is it displaying 70 rows out of the 154 rows if the connection is not working

Comment: What I meant is have you confirmed that you are connecting to the same data source from both tools.

Comment: @KamilG.Yes, I I'm getting the data from multiple tables in the same database, and to be more specific 2 columns from a left joined table are only showing null values where I know that those values are not null. I have a co worker that ran the same query on his Power BI and he is getting the full result it's only my Power BI, and I have uninstalled and re-installed the application